# My insert statement is executing twice and i'm not sure why. sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an insert statement.

```
   conn = sqlite3.connect('WO1.db')


   with conn:
           cur1 = conn.cursor()
           cur1.execute("insert into workorder (Title, Link, Status) 
    values (?,?,?)", ('iijiji', 'ijjijijj', '22jhhuhij'))

   if conn:
           conn.close()
```

The title and link columns had UNIQUE constraints on them and I was getting the following error and my program terminated.

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed:
```

But 1 new record inserted into the database which is what I wanted.

I then created a new table where the Title and Link columns didn't have a UNIQUE constraint.

I ran the program again and this time received no error however, the record was inserted into the table twice which explains the error when there was UNIQUE constraints on the Link and Title.

Is there any logical explanation as to why this insert statement is executing twice?

Note This is only one place in the program where a connection is established, a query is executed and then the connection is closed. There is no other interaction with this database in the program other than the normal configuration.

I haven't had any other sessions open with this database either other than within this application.

I'm running this query in the python file where the program is run from.

```
   app = Flask(__name__)

   app.config.from_object(Config)

   db = SQLAlchemy(app)

   conn = sqlite3.connect('WO1.db')


   with conn:
          cur1 = conn.cursor()
         cur1.execute("insert into workorder (Title, Link, Status) values 
  (?,?,?)", ('en24433', 'www.reddit.com', 'Not Completed'))

 if conn:
         conn.close()


 migrate = Migrate(app, db)


 @app.route('/')
 def index():
     return render_template('index.html')

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug= True)
```

Comment: Check your server log, I'll bet something is calling the controller twice.

Comment: I didn't check my server log but I did put the connection to the db and insert statement's within the '/' route rather than above the route's and it worked exactly how I wanted when I opened up my index on my browser. The insert statement executed once. Cheers for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I put the database connection and insert statements into my index route rather than above the routes.

```
 app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object(Config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

migrate = Migrate(app, db)


@app.route('/')
 def index():
     conn = sqlite3.connect('WO1.db')

     with conn:
         cur1 = conn.cursor()
         cur1.execute("insert into work_order (Title, Link, Status) values (?,?,?)",
                     ('iikii', 'ijkoijj', '66hhuhij'))
       conn.close()

       return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your need to remake your database access code.

Firstly you connect twice at the same db by using the `with` statement after `conn.connect()`.

> When a database is accessed by multiple connections, and one of the processes modifies the database, the SQLite database is locked until that transaction is committed.

I think that this is the **reason for your error**.

After you make the insert in database you need to commit the changes.

> This method commits the current transaction. If you don’t call this method, anything you did since the last call to commit() is not visible from other database connections. If you wonder why you don’t see the data you’ve written to the database, please check you didn’t forget to call this method.

Be aware that **close()** does not automatically commit:

> This closes the database connection. Note that this does not automatically call commit(). If you just close your database connection without calling commit()first, your changes will be lost!

Take a look at [sqlite3 API docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)